# How do I put Internet Explorer 11 into FIPS 140-2 mode

Tags: internet-explorer-11, fips

In our application,we are enabled FIPS With Java1.7 with NSS3.12 Version.

configuration in java.security file:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 D:\\7002FIPS\\Windows\\nss.cfg
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider SunPKCS11-NSSFIPS
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
security.provider.11=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

nss.cfg

```
name=NSSFIPS
nssLibraryDirectory=D:\\7002FIPS\Windows\lib
nssSecmodDirectory=D:\\7002FIPS\Windows\cert
nssDbMode=readWrite
nssModule=fips
```

Followed below configurations able to connect to my web-client in Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Configuring%20Firefox%20for%20FIPS%20140-2

By default able to connect my web-client in chrome browser without any configurations in the browser settings.

But not able to connect to my web-client in IE11 browser? Am i missing any configuration in the Browser setting ??

Comment: What *exactly* happens in Internet Explorer when you attempt to connect to the site? What is its URL? Have you configured Windows itself to run in FIPS mode? IE11 disabled RC4 by default, which may be a factor here.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  

Yes, We had enabled windows in FIPS mode by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886368/how-to-enable-fips-on-windows-7 steps mentioned it.

Regarding url https://Myserver-name:port

Comment: What exactly happens in Internet Explorer when you attempt to connect to the site?

Comment: Getting as 'This page can’t be displayed' while try to connect to <my-server> with port.    Continued in the next post..

Comment: Getting below mentioned dnserror.html

//used by new dnserror.htm
var L_INTERNET_NOT_CONNECTED_TEXT =3D "You\u2019re not connected to a =
network";var L_INTERNET_CONNECTED_TEXT =3D "This page can\u2019t be displayed";
var L_TLS_SSL_TEXT =3D "Make sure TLS and SSL protocols are enabled. Go =
to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Settings > Security";
// Used by IM DNS error page As my machine dns is correct and able to connect with Chrome  and also tried enable/Diable  TLS and SSL protocols in the security Setting page. Let me know any further details ???

Comment: If you run Fiddler (with HTTPS decryption disabled, as it is by default) what is the text of the TEXTVIEW request inspector on the CONNECT tunnel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @user3557172 -  Please take those multi-posts comments and add them to your question. Then, delete the comments. You can add them to your question by clicking *Edit*.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I put Internet Explorer 11 into FIPS 140-2 mode

See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article ["System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" security setting effects in Windows XP and in later versions of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833/en-us).

> ... but not able to connect to my web-client in IE11 browser?

This is a different question. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.