# imageresizer with FIPS compliance issue

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm using imageresizer with diskcache, and it works great.  The only problem is that if i turn on FIPS compliance on the server/client ( see [How to enable FIPS on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886368/how-to-enable-fips-on-windows-7) for an example on how to do this if you need it ), it doesn't work at all.  I can clear out the images from the diskcache folder, and imageresizer won't fill it back up when this setting is turned on.  See
https://gist.github.com/vishnu4/ced29ca01b37957a90f6 for a diagnostic sheet, which doesn't seem to show any errors.
Is there a good workaround for this, or is FIPS compliance just not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't use FIPS compliant modules exclusively. There are a few reasons for this, but primarily it's to escape implementation bugs in the Windows cryptography modules and portability issues with the same.

That said, we could probably create and maintain a FIPS-compliant operating mode if we had a support contract with a user who needed FIPS-compliance.

But using FIPS-compliant modules wouldn't be a good choice for default operation, so it's not something we would consider a bug or design flaw.  Also keep in mind that unless you're using the RemoteReader plugin, ImageResizer isn't doing any cryptography, just hashing for cache optimization purposes. Unfortunately, FIPS-compliance is quite context-blind.

Comment: Thanks!  I just needed to be sure.